# overloaded ++ operator isn't working in c++

Tags: c++

Can someone explain to me why my overloaded ++ (pre version) isn't updating the value? Snippet is like this:

```
circle circle:: operator++()
{  
    Area = Area * 2.0;
    return *this; 
}
/////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    class circle c1(4, 1, -1), c2(12, 4, 6);
    c1.output();
    c1++;
    c1.output();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aren't you calling postfix version `c1++`?

Comment: Also you need to check your [signatures](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) as your version doesn't match

Comment: The signature for post increment `c1++` requires you to implement `circle& circle::operator++(int)`. Your current implementation of `operator++()` will work for  pre increment `++c1`

Comment: @Vishal It would work for preincrement but it should return a reference

Answer (score 7):

It's because you overload the prefix and call the postfix. You need to call `++c1;`. To use `c1++;` you need to overload the postfix as well:

```
  circle operator++ ( int );
```

Comment: Can you update your answer to mention the other possible fix? The OP may have meant to call `c1++;`

Comment: Yes, I should do it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The [signature](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) of your overload operator should be:

```
circle& operator++();   // return by reference and this is prefix.
```

But you use postfix, so it should be:

```
circle operator++ (int);   // int is unused
```

**Changing the signature is not enough** because you implement a prefix logic, directly changing the value without saving the initial value.  So if you'd use postfix operator with your implementation in a combined expression like `(c++).output()`, it would not respect the expected semantic.

Here the implemetnation of both version:

```
circle& operator++ () {  // prefix
    Area = Area * 2.0;   // you can change directly the value
    cout << "prefix"<<endl; 
    return *this;        // and return the object which contains new value
}

circle operator++ (int) {  // postfix
    circle c(*this);     // you must save current state 
    Area = Area * 2.0;   // then you update the object 
    cout << "postfix"<<endl; 
    return c;            // then you have to return the value before the operation 
}
```

And here an [online demo](http://ideone.com/9Caq48) to show difference between both.

Comment: True, but that wouldn't change the result. OP isn't using the expression directly. The error has been highlighted in the comments.

Comment: Does't circle& operator++(); require a parameter of class or enum type?

Comment: @TaimurAhmed yes indeed  for the postfix increment.  I was completing my answer while you were typing.

Comment: postfix operator should return a value, not a reference.

Comment: @paddy that's exact.  And it should return the initial value, not the updated one.

Comment: @TaimurAhmed have you looked at the online demo ? It displays area value in every case showing that the value is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is both version prefix and post fix. And you can add some code in case of a call like *c1++(1);*  (of course if needed)

```
circle circle:: operator++() // prefix version
{  
    Area = Area * 2.0;
    return *this; 
}

circle& circle::operator++( int n ) {    //postfix version
    if( n != 0 )                // Handle case where an argument is passed.
       //some code
    else
        Area = Area * 2.0;       // Handle case where no argument is passed.
    return *this;
}


int main()
{
    class circle c1(4, 1, -1), c2(12, 4, 6);
    c1.output();
    c1++;
    ++c1;
    c1.output();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```